# Get an HTML element's line number

Tags: html, dom, element, codemirror, ace-editor

Was wondering if there is a better way to find an elements line number in the sources code.

This is what i've go so far:

```
// Get the item that the user is clicking on:
var focused = doc.getSelection().anchorNode;
if(focused.nodeType == 3){ // text node
    focused = focused.parentNode;
}

// Get the entire page as a string
// NOTE: <!doctype> is not included in this!
var pageStr = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;

// Get the focused node's parent and 
// find where it begins in the page.
var parentNodeStr   = focused.outerHTML;
var parentNodeIndex = pageStr.indexOf(parentNodeStr);

// Find where the focused node begins in it's parent.
var focusedStr      = focused.outerHTML;
var focusedIndex    = parentNodeStr.indexOf(focusedStr);

// Now find where the focused node begins in the overall page.
var actualIndex     = parentNodeIndex - focusedIndex;

// Grab the text above the focused node
// and count the number of lines.
var contentAbove    = pageStr.substr(0, actualIndex);
var lineNumbers     = contentAbove.split("\n").length;

console.log("lineCount", lineNumbers);
```

Comment: two pennies note : `doc.documentElement.outerHTML;` will give you the computed html, not the original source of the .html file, lines might not match. (one way could be to read the original file from XHR)

Comment: I agree and have a new solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better solution I've come up with, hopefully this will help someone down the road that's using Ace or CodeMirror in conjunction with contenteditable:

**Setup (for newbies)**

We can obtain where the user is selecting using:

```
var sel = document.getSelection();
```

The beginning of the selection is called the "anchor"
and the end is called "focus". For example,
when you select a few words of text, there is
a beginning and an end of the selection.

```
var anchorPoint = elementPointInCode(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
var focusPoint = elementPointInCode(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
```

Since HTML contains tags and readable text, there is an
offset. For example:

```
<p>abcdefgh</p>
// ...^
```

The offset is the index within the text node string.
In our example the letter "d" is offset by 4 characters
from the entry point of the &gtp&lt tag.
But the offset is zero based, so the offset is actually 3.

We get the offset using:

```
var offset = sel.anchorOffset;
// -- or --
var offset = sel.focusOffset;
```

... depending on what we want, the beginning of end.

**Function**

```
function elementPointInCode(element, offset) {

    // There may or may not be an offset.
    offset =  offset || 0;

    var node = element;

    // Process first node because it'll more-than-likely be a text node.
    // And we don't want to go matching text against any of the node HTML.
    //  e.g. <a href="page.html">page 1</a>
    //      where the text "page" sould match the "page" within the <a> attributes.

    var strIndex;
    var str;

    // Bump text nodes up to parent
    if(node.nodeType == 3) {
        node = node.parentNode;
        str = node.outerHTML;
        strIndex = str.indexOf(">") + offset + 1;
    } else {
        strIndex = ;
    }

    // This will ultimately contain the HTML string of the root node.
    var parentNodeStr = "";
    while(node){

        // Get the current node's HTML.
        var str = node.outerHTML;

        // Preemptively snag the parent
        var parent = node.parentNode;

        if(parent && str){

            // The <html> root, we won't have a parent.
            var outer = parent.outerHTML;

            if(outer){

                // Stash the node's HTML for post processing.
                parentNodeStr = outer;

                // Cumulatively count the offset's within each node
                strIndex += parentNodeStr.indexOf( str );

            }

        }

        // Work our way up to the root
        node = parent;

    }

    // Chop the root HTML by our cumulative string index
    var str = parentNodeStr.substr(0, strIndex);

    var Astr = str.split("\n" );

    return {
        row : Astr.length,
        col : Astr.pop().length
    }

};
```